# gnome system monitor doesn't show read-write of other applications, or actual CPU usage

Tags: gnome, system-monitor

Well the "processes" page of the gnome-system-monitor application seems to show very faulty data. The diskread total and diskwrite total for any application is "N/A" (even though I know certain applications save to disk, and I am trying to debug this, since disk seems to constantly run & seem to lag down the whole system).

On top of that the actual cpu usage is always "0" for any application, yet in the "resources" tab I see total cpu be somewhere around 20-40%.

What is causing these problems and how can I fix it to find which process is keeping my hard drive busy?

---

On request here is a log of the system monitor while webstorm is loading (and I actually hear the hard drive being busy, and cpu is also not zero). The process marked (java) is what corresponds to webstorm ide: which is actively loading.
I'm using ubuntu 18.04

[image: Log]

Comment: Hey, would you mind posting a screenshot?  It may be just my version of the sys monitor, but I don't have anything that looks like diskread or diskwrite.  Also, what types of processes are you showing (yours, active, or all?)  Furthermore, what kind of specs do you have on your system?

Comment: @anonymous2 Just added the picture, as shown it only shows my processes

Comment: @N0rbert what does that have anything to do with the inner workings? And the inability to check other applications?

Comment: @N0rbert how can I see this? The system monitor is just installed as per default in my system, so I guess with 18.04 it is snap. However that doesn't solve the problem, the question linked is asking why it is installed as snap. It shouldn't misbehave since it's a default application? So there must be something else wrong.

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the %CPU column so that it sorts by CPU usage?  The most CPU usage will appear at the top of the list.  The way that pic shows, it has it listing the lowest at the top.

Comment: @Terrance as you can see by the little triangle it is already sorted that way; though the main problem are the N/A  on disk read/write totals.

Comment: The little triangle points up, not down.

Comment: @Terrance yes, I just tested that in the CPU-time column and when it points "up" the highest value is at top. - But nevertheless I tested both.

Comment: Strange, it should be the other way around.  That is how it is working for me here.  I am using 18.04 as well.  https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/37564/use-up-or-down-arrow-to-represent-sort-ascending-at-table-header

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as yours. so I removed gnome-system-monitor (3.20.2) in Ubuntu Software and install gnome-system-monitor with `sudo apt install gnome-system-monitor` (3.28.2) and disk IO works.